# Is there a FogBugz plugin for Tortoise SVN to query issues on commit?

Tags: tortoisesvn, fogbugz

I want to be able to choose from a list of fogbugz issues when I commit from TSVN - rather than remember the issue number.

Similar to [gurtle](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/339) and [TracExplorer](http://tracexplorer.devjavu.com/)

See the very bottom of this page:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html

If not available, perhaps I will try to re-use the best of the code of those other two (Assuming open source and decent licensing) to add FB.

If anyone else is interested in working on this let me know.

Comment: @Tom - have you created the plugin?

Comment: no - I have been working on another venture but this is still on the back burner.  I have no idea if/when I will get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice... I don't think there is such thing, but it should be very easy to create it using [FogBugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html)

Fog Creek publishes list of 3rd party tools that work with FogBugz at http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W724 and http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/Ecology.html

When you create such tool, please post link here or to ecology pages. I am interested :-)

Comment: Yes, it should be rather straightforward, but I just want to check before I write my own.